# query() and isin() combination is not working in Kaggle notebook

Tags: python, isin

I want to filter dataframe using .query() and .isin() functions in Kaggle notebook.

```
standard_stats=standard_stats.query('`Unnamed: 0_level_0_Player`.isin(["Squad Total","Opponent Total"])==False')
```

`Unnamed: 0_level_0_Player` is the name of the column and ["Squad Total","Opponent Total"]  is the list of values, that should not be in the filtered dataframe.

After running this code, I get the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.

I did not get the error, when I ran the code in Jupyter Notebook.
How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: This is probably not a full solution, but you are using back ticks: ` rather than single quotes: '

Comment: I am using backticks, because it is required in Pandas query function when the column name contains space. There was no issue, when I ran the same code in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  If your question include a pandas dataframe, please provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: kaggle notebook can be found on this link: https://www.kaggle.com/code/beridzeg45/notebook3a64db585b/edit

Answer (score 0):

The .isin() func does not accept the np array you passed, because an np array is a non hashable object.
try using the .loc()

```
standard_stats = standard_stats.loc[~standard_stats['Unnamed: 0_level_0_Player'].isin(["Squad Total", "Opponent Total"])]
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: I modified my answer, @beridzeg45 can you check the .loc()